# QT5/6 C++ getting all checkboxes

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently doing a QT5 course and in the course it covers checkboxes, the course shows us the following way to get all the checkboxes from the view and put them in a foreach like so, granted it works, but it seems a lot like going round the houses to find something that in other languages can be found in a much simpler way:

```
void MainWindow::on_btnSubmit_clicked()
{
    QString toppings;
    QObjectList boxes = this->centralWidget()->children(); // gets all of the children and checks for checkboxes

    foreach(QObject* obj, boxes) {
        if(obj->inherits("QCheckBox")) {
            QCheckBox* thisBox = qobject_cast<QCheckBox*>(obj);
            if(thisBox && thisBox->isChecked()) {
                toppings += thisBox->text() + "\r\n";
                qInfo() << thisBox;
            }
        }
    }

    QMessageBox::information(this, "Toppings selected", "Toppings you added: \n\n" + toppings);

}
```

This is my view:
[image]

My question is, is there no better way of achieving this? It seems this would be a kind of silly way to do it if there was a lot of things in the view.

Comment: Can you describe the simpler way that other languages use that you're hoping exists in Qt?

Comment: You can use [QObject::findChildren<>](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren) instead the foreach loop (btw: foreach is depreacted - don't use it anymore)

Comment: there is `std::foreach` but it is unclear what `foreach` in your code is supposed to be. Looks a bit like a function definition, but it isnt. Is it a macro?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 It's the [`foreach`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#foreach) macro included in Qt.

Comment: I would use findChildren and a range based for loop.

Comment: @chehrlic thanks for that I've changed my query a little to the following: QList<QCheckBox *> boxes = this->findChildren<QCheckBox *>(); and it picks up only checkboxes which is what I was after. How do I iterate through it now, I looked into the docs and people are saying for loop?

Comment: You should know how to loop over a container when you want to use c/c++ or any other language. https://www.tutorialcup.com/cplusplus/for-loop.htm

Comment: @chehrlic oh my bad I didnt realise I can just use a normal c++ loop now, I thought there may have been something like the now depreacted foreach

Comment: `for (auto& pCheckBox :  boxes) { // do something with pCheckBox }`